# Symfony 2, get entity from Many To Many association

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many

I have entity `Product` and `Tires`. 
One Product has more Tires and one Tire can be on more Products.

In my controller when I call

```
$product = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->find($id);
```

or

```
$tires = $product->getExtraTires();
```

> Related Tires won't return.

```
/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Product {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->extraTires = new ArrayCollection();
    }

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tires", mappedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_tires",
     *       joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *       inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tires_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $extraTires;

   /**
     * Get extraTires
     *
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
     public function getExtraTires()
     {
         return $this->extraTires;
     }

    /**
      * Add extraTires
      *
      * @param Tires $extraTires
      * @return Product
      */

      public function addExtraTire(Tires $extraTires)
      {
          $this->extraTires[] = $extraTires;

          return $this;
      }

     /**
      * Remove extraTires
      *
      * @param \Wielton\WieltonBundle\Entity\Tires $extraTires
      */
      public function removeExtraTire(Tires $extraTires)
      {
          $this->extraTires->removeElement($extraTires);
      }
```

And my Tires entity

```
/**
 * Tires
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Tires")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */    
class Tires {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="extraTires")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_tires",
     *       joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tires_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *       inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
     private $products;

    /**
     * Add products
     *
     * @param Product $products
     * @return Tires
     */
     public function addProduct(Product $products)
    {
        $this->products[] = $products;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove products
     *
     * @param Product $products
     */
     public function removeProduct(Product $products)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($products);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
     public function getProducts()
     {
        return $this->products;
     }
```

I designed entities according [doctrine doctumentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). When I add Product and choose tires to add everything looks ok in join table.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I found something, but I don't fully understand how does it work :)

In my controller when Im getting Product entity with

```
$product = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->find($id);
```

I have to go in twig into 
    product.extraTires.owner.extraTires
And then I can see my associated tires here. And suddenly I have one more query to the database. So somehow I'm not calling it in controller properly.

**SOLUTION**
Seems like query in controller wasn't complete. `$tires` now return array of tires, you can also use ->getValues() method.

```
$product = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->find($id);
$tires = $product->getExtraTires()->toArray();
```

Comment: How does look like your tests code?

Comment: Im not sure if functional test will be any good here. I tried to make this tone but its just return empty array with tires http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html

Comment: Just a stupid question but do you have "tires" in database ? Your class `tired` have the `@ORM\Entity` annotation ?

Comment: @zilongqiu sorry I forget to copy annotation into class here, anyway I just added it here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine will not update automatically the in-memory hydrated object. The in-memory PHP object will not contain updated relation until you hydrate it again from the database or you update the in-memory representation yourself.

Try to modify adders like the following (I let you look how to do that for the removers but it's the same idea):

Product:

```
class Product
{

    public function addExtraTire(Tires $extraTires)
    {
        $this->extraTires[] = $extraTires;

        if (!$extraTires->getProducts()->contains($this) {
            $extraTires->addProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Tires:

```
class Tires
{
    public function addProduct(Product $products)
    {
            $this->products[] = $products;

            if (!$products->getExtraTires()->contains($this) {
                $products->addExtraTire($this);
            }

            return $this;
    }
}
```